# How to set XMLFormatter with FileHandler to only write raw message

Tags: java, logging, filehandler

I'm using java `FileHandler` to append to a file, and occasionally rotate it. The data consists of JSON strings, one on each line. The file is consumed by another process, and I want the `FileHandler` to only write the JSON string I pass into the publish method, without any xml metadata. How is this accomplished? I've scoured the internet for information about `XMLFormatter` and `FileHandler`, but all I've found are content farm tutorials that barely touch on the basics. Right now, I get the following written to the file:

```
<record>
  <date>2016-01-06T15:05:54</date>
  <millis>1452121554535</millis>
  <sequence>14</sequence>
  <level>INFO</level>
  <thread>29</thread>
  <message>MyMessage</message>
</record>
```

And all I want written is MyMessage.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What about implementing a custom `java.util.logging.Formatter`?

Comment: Aha yes, I just pulled my copy of Core Java off the shelf, and that is the approach they suggest as well!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a custom formatter then you can use the [java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html) and set the `format` property to `%5$s` which will just write out the message part of the log record.

```
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format = %5$s
```

It won't work if you require another SimpleFormatter with a different pattern like a ConsoleHandler or if your raw data trips up [MessageFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) patterns.